# Python RSA Encryption calculate valid length of plaintext

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm developing a program that encrypts and decrypts using RSA (in python). I've read that using only RSA is not secure and it's recommended to use PCKS to do that. My main problem is how to efficiently calculate the length of the plain text i can encrypt and decrypt using a PCKS (taking in account I'm using 4096 bit key it should be less than 512 byte and I think I have to take some bytes that the PCKS uses in account).

To sum up: How do I efficiently get the length (or split) the plain text in order to encrypt/decrypt (and how do I manage to now how many bytes takes de PCSK)?

Bonus Question: Why is it insecure just to cipher a plaintext with RSA?

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, I will use an AES symmetric key to encrpyt/decrypt and share the key with RSA. According to that change, Will python calculate the encrpytion/decryption by itself of all the plaintext or do I have to split it (and how to do it efficiently if it can be done)?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Questions about the design and implementation of cryptography algorithms are more suited to [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com). While it can be interesting and educational to write cryptography code you should _not_ use your own code for anything that _really_ needs to be secure unless you _really_ know what you're doing. The first rule of crypto is: Don't roll your own crypto!

Comment: But anyway... I assume by "PKCS" you mean Private Key Crypto System. RSA is quite secure if used properly. However, it is very computationally intensive, which makes it slow compared to a symmetric cypher like AES. So we normally use AES (or some other similarly strong symmetric cypher) with a random key to encrypt the plaintext, and we use RSA to encrypt that AES key.

Comment: Well I only need to encrypt very few messages but, In case I shared a symmetric key with a timestamp (in order to avoid reply attack) encrpyted in a single RSA message...Is there anyway to efficiently calculate how to split the plaintext to encrypt with a symmetric cipher (aka AES) or do I have to loop over the text calculating the byte length?(or will a Python library calculate it for me and cipher the text in one function call)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [General overview of PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/): "This documentation assumes you have some basic knowledge about the Python language, but not necessarily about cryptography." However, from your questions, I suspect that you may need to improve your core Python skills first before getting too involved with this crypto project. In Python, all of the built-in collection types (including lists, strings and bytes objects) store their size, and that size can be accessed with the `len` built-in function.

Comment: Thats only if you want to get the size of the object but not the byte size (for example a list a=['abc','def'] has len of 2 but size of 80). To get the byte size you have to use sys.getsizeof(object[, default]). If the size with len would be the same I won't be asking this question (I'm suposing encryption methods use byte size of plaintext not the len).

Comment: Encryption functions work with blocks of bytes. So in Python 3 you encode your plaintext string to a `bytes` string, and pass that `bytes` string to the encryption function. Eg, if your plaintext is `s = "my secret message"` you would do something like `encrypt(s.encode())`. The ` s.encode()` call encodes the Unicode string object `s` into a UTF-* byte string, which is 17 bytes long. The encryption library then pads that byte string to make it the required block size for AES (or whatever algorithm you're using). You can read about this stuff in the link I posted earlier.

Comment: I've answered this [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/1172) for OAEP. For PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (less secure) the overhead is simply 11 bytes (4096 / 8 - 11 should give you the octets), see [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32558/1172) for more info. Feel free to upvote my answers at crypto.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about cryptography (crypto.stackexchange.com) rather than the Python API, and the question has actually be answered there for both OAEP and PKCS#1 v1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first say that it is very easy to implement cryptography wrong, so unless you have been spending many years studying it (you have not -- which is clear from how you wrote your question), you shouldn't be writing crypto code that is used in production.  For example, the errors you return can be used to break the crypto in a [Bleichenbacher attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/can-you-explain-bleichenbachers-cca-attack-on-pkcs1-v1-5).  However, if you are only doing it for learning activities, then here is some guidance.

You have a choice between implementing the insecure [PKCS #1 v1.5 padding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313) or the more secure [PKCS #1 v2.x OAEP padding](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf).  Everything you need to know is in the standard: you should follow it to a T.

To answer your question, for the OAEP version you need message length ≤ modulus length – 2 * hash function output length – 2, where lengths are in bytes.

Example 2048-bit modulus using SHA256 hash.  2048-bits is 256 bytes.  Hash function has 256-bits output, which is 32 bytes.  So your message must be ≤ 256 - 2*32 - 2 = 256 - 64 - 2 = 190 bytes.

Since you understand that RSA should be used for encrypting a symmetric key such as AES, you know that such keys are no longer than 256-bits, which is 32 bytes.  It comfortably fits into the 190-byte limit.

Why is textbook RSA insecure?  Well, three decades of cryptography has transformed an interesting concept (RSA), that we want to be as difficult to break as factoring, into something that we can almost prove that breaking it is as difficult as factoring under some crazy random oracle assumption.  The only way we got to this more secure version (OAEP) was by ruling out the heuristic versions that constantly got broken.  If you want to read in depth about the history of broken designs, the best paper is [Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf).

However, let me give you a little insight into the theory of what is wrong with textbook RSA.  A cryptosystem should be secure even if a single bit of information is encrypted.  Suppose Markov sends an encrypted message to Sanchez where the plaintext is a single bit.  If Zhang sees the ciphertext, can he determine what the plaintext is?  With textbook RSA, the answer is yes.  All he has to do is encrypt '1' and '0' with the same public key and see which one matches the ciphertext he captured.  Lesson: for security, you need that encrypting the same message twice does not result in the same ciphertext twice.  Hence, secure encryption requires randomness brought into the equation!